# Proof of Kaplansky density theorem

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am learning Kaplansky density theorem, there is a problem as following:

If $C$ is a unital $C^*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ and $A$ is its SOT clousure, $ReA$ and $ReC$ is set of self adjoint elements in $A$ and $C$, ball$ReA$ and ball$ReC$ is the closed unit ball of $ReA$ and $ReC$.

And I find a proof in a book: the author firstly prove that $ReA$ is the SOT clousre of $ReC$, because $\forall x\in ReA$, there exist $\{x_i\}\subset C$ such that $x_i \rightarrow x$ in *-SOT by von Neumann double commutant theorem, thus also $x_i^* \rightarrow x$ in *-SOT, thus $\frac{1}{2}(x_i^*+x_i)\rightarrow x$ in SOT, thus $ReA \subset \overline{ReC}^{SOT}$

Now I want to ask that weather $\overline{ReC}^{SOT}\subset ReA $ ? i.e. the SOT limit of a sequence of self adjoint elements in the $C^*$-algebra is a self adjoint element or not ?

Comment: A useful proposition is that involution (which is in generaly not continuous with respect to SOT) is actually continuous when restricted to the subset of normal elements. Since self-adjoint elements are normal, you can simply apply involution to get that the adjoint of the sot limit is the same as itself. You can find a proof of this in Murphy's book. Of course Martin's answer is the easiest way to go, but I thought it would be a good thing to keep in mind:)

Comment: @JustDroppedln, thanks for your proposition. Could you tell me the title of the Murphy's book? Is it C*-Algebras and Operator Theory? Thank you!

Comment: @JustDroppedIn That does not work. Involution being strongly continuous on the set of normal operators only means that whenever a net of normal operators converges to a *normal* operator, the adjoints converge strongly to the adjoint. It is an essential assumption that the limit is normal.

Comment: @MaoWao yes, you are right. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for noticing.

Comment: @John please have a look at MaoWao's comment!

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Yes, thanks for your reminder, I have seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because sot implies wot. Note that you cannot use sequences in general, you have to use nets. If $\{a_j\}\subset C$ consists of selfadjoints and $a_j\to a$ sot, then
$$
\langle a^*\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle \xi,a\xi\rangle=\lim_j\langle \xi,a_j\xi\rangle=\lim_j\langle a_j\xi,\xi\rangle=\langle a\xi,\xi\rangle.
$$
As this works for all $\xi\in H$, you get that $a^*=a$.

Comment: Thank you, dear Martin Argerami, you helped me many times. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: You are very welcome. Please upvote! :)